# Autowiring returns a NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I have an interface `RestService` and a `RestServiceImpl` class shown below:

//RestService:

```
public interface RestService {

    public void printMessage();
}
```

//RestServiceImpl:

```
@Service
public class RestServiceImpl implements RestService {

    public RestServiceImpl() {

    }

    public void printMessage() {
        System.out.println("This is a test message.");

    }

}
```

When testing the printMessage() method, I get a NullPointerException.  I'm pretty sure I autowired everything correctly and have added the appropriate annotations to the classes. Not sure why this is happening.

```
@SpringBootTest
public class RestServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    RestService restService;

    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        restService.printMessage(); //Thows NullPointerException
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What you're missing is to show us the test configuration. Did you follow all the steps in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html)?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, make sure the whole spring infrastructure is plugged in, a "bridge" between the JUnit framework and spring:

There is no `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` on the test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class RestServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    RestService restService;

    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        restService.printMessage(); //Thows NullPointerException
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` at top of `RestServiceTest`.